# is win32::OLE supported in linux?

Tags: linux, perl, automation, perl-module, cpan

I have a task of manipulating a csv file and fetch the data, 
i tried installing **Win32::OLE** in linux but it gave a bad operating system message and terminated while installing 
does that mean this package in not supported on linux environment

Also would like to know which package in perl would be neccessary for manipulating ***.csv*** or ***.xls*** files

Comment: That looks like two totally different questions.

Comment: Windows != Linux. See Text::CSV for manipulating CSV files.

Comment: I think the hint is in the name.... win32::

Comment: Should a bifid question be closed as "too broad" ?

Comment: Linux "from box" supports csv! Just read `man sed`, `man grep`, `man awk`…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot use the Win32::OLE module in Linux because it uses the Windows API.
If you need to work with CSV and XLS:

- CSV files: [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV), [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS), [Parse::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Parse%3a%3aCSV)
- XLS files: [Spreadsheet::Read](http://p3rl.org/Spreadsheet%3a%3aRead)
- XLSX files: [Spreadsheet::XLSX](http://p3rl.org/Spreadsheet%3a%3aXLSX)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be possible to use OLE through Wine.

From: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=430194

> Download and install Windows Installer 2.0 Redistributable for Windows
> 95, 98, and Me Download latest Active State Perl for Windows in .msi
> format. E.g. ActivePerl-5.8.6.811-MSWin32-x86-122208.msi.
>
> Start installation:
>
> $ /opt/cxoffice/bin/wine "C:~WB~WINDOWS~WB~SYSTEM~WB~msiexec.exe" /i ActivePerl-5.8.6.811-MSWin32-x86-122208.msi
>
> $ /opt/cxoffice/bin/wine "c:\Perl\bin\perl.exe" -v